# MvvmCross: MvxTableViewCell binding from outside

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I've created a `MvxTableViewCell` subclass that I plan to reuse at many points of my App, so I want to delegate the binding task to the creator of the cell.

So far, I got this working based on some [N+1 tutorial](http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com) examples, mainly [this code](https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-17-CollectABull-Part6/CollectABull.Touch/Views/ListView.cs) from [N=17-Collect a Bull part 3](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n17-from-wp-and-android-to-touch-n1.html) tutorial.

So at this point, creating a cell looks like this:

```
return new SubtitleCell("TitleText Name; SubtitleText Subject.Descripcion"))
```

But I don't really like bindings defined in strings, because I usually refactor a lot and this may cause troubles in the near future, so I decided to declare the binding like a normal bindable view like this:

```
var cell = new SubtitleCell();
var set = cell.CreateBindingSet<SubtitleCell, SubjectGroup>();
set.Bind().For(c => c.TitleText).To(g => g.Name);
set.Bind().For(c => c.SubtitleText).To(g => g.Subject.Descripcion);
set.Apply();
return cell;
```

This now works like before and now it's refactor-safe, but it's six times the lines of code that I had before and the binding must be defined when the instance of the cell is already created.

I think that it can be done using `MvxBindingDescription` because the binding text used in the first example is parsed to a `IEnumerable<MvxBindingDescription>`, but I was unable to find an example or documentation about it.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
LoC is not my biggest concern, but having to instantiate each cell before defining the binding, I'd be happy to have something like this:

```
var set = Mvx.CreateBindingSet<SubtitleCell, SubjectGroup>();
set.Bind().For(c => c.TitleText).To(g => g.Name);
set.Bind().For(c => c.SubtitleText).To(g => g.Subject.Descripcion);
```

So I can apply it later maybe like this:

```
var cell = new SubtitleCell();
cell.ApplyBindingSet(set);
```

Is there something that can be done moving this way?

**UPDATE:**
Just noticed that the second binding example fills my log console with this error:

```
MvxBind:Warning:  0.40 Unable to bind: source property source not found
Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.PropertyPath.PropertyTokens.MvxPropertyNamePropertyToken on null-object
```

Both samples seems to produce the same behavior, but the warning errors only appear using fluent binding.

Answer (score 1):

MvxBindingDescription won't really help with refactoring - it operates just above the text or fluent bindings and just below the reflection level of the binding engine.

If you want `Expression` based binding for refactoring, then you have to use Fluent binding and pay the penalty of the extra lines of code (if you consider that a penalty)

Comment: Thanks for your response Stuart, please see my edit for more details.